# Computer Vision: Opencv Counting small circles inside big circle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

Here is the image on which i have been working on
[image]

The goal is to detect small circles inside the big one.

currently what i have done is converted the image to gray scale and applied threshold (cv2.THRESH_OTSU) to which resulted in this image
[image]

After this i have filtered out large objects using findcontours applied Morph open using elliptical shaped kernel which i found on stackoverflow

The result image is like this
[image]

Can someone guide me through the correct path on what to do and where i'm getting wrong.

Below is attached code on which i have been working on

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('01.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
#cv2.imwrite('thresh.jpg', thresh)

# Filter out large non-connecting objects
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    #print(area)
    if area < 200 and area > 0:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh,[c],0,0,-1)

# Morph open using elliptical shaped kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)

# Find circles 
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 20 and area < 50:
        ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (36, 255, 12), 2)

cv2.namedWindow('orig', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('orig', thresh)
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Thank you!

Comment: An idea that might be helpful, if you get the contour of the biggest circle , then all the contours inside it will be for smaller circles that you want. So, try to identify the biggest circle.

Comment: I guess that you can sacrifice the few dots against the "big circle". Then filtering the blobs  on size is an easy matter.

Answer (score 6):

You throw away a lot of useful information by converting your image to grayscale.

Why not use the fact that the spots you are looking for are the only thing that is red/orange?

I multiplied the saturaton channel with the red channel which gave me this image:

[image]

Now finding the white blobs becomes trivial.

Experiment with different weights for those channels, or apply thresholds first. There are many ways. Experiment with different illumination, different backgrounds until you get the ideal input for your image processing.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see what information is lost. The image has essentially two colors and is even close to binary.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is the flag that you are using in cv2.findContours() function.

For such a problem in which we have to find contours which can appear inside another contour(the big circle), we should not use the flag cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, instead use cv2.RETR_TREE. [Click here for detailed info.](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html).

Also, it is always better to use cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE instead of cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE if memory is not an issue. [Click here for detailed info.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

Thus, the following simple code can be used to solve this problem.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

Image = cv2.imread("Adg5.jpg")
GrayImage = cv2.cvtColor(Image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Applying Otsu's Thresholding
Retval, ThreshImage = cv2.threshold(GrayImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Finding Contours in the image
Contours, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(ThreshImage, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Taking only those contours which have no child contour.
FinalContours = [Contours[i] for i in range(len(Contours)) if Hierarchy[0][i][2] == -1]

# Drawing contours
Image = cv2.drawContours(Image, FinalContours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("Contours", Image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Resulting image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LkUfH6lLM2MoEo0kdbDqc6pA2kHSyhfN/view?usp=sharing)
In this method, a lot of noise at the boundary is also coming but the required orange points are also being detected. Now the task is to remove boundary noise.

Another method that removes boundary noise to a great extent is similar to @Piglet 's approach.
Here, I am using HSV image to segment out the orange points and then detecting them using the above approach.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

Image = cv2.imread("Adg5.jpg")
HSV_Image = cv2.cvtColor(Image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Extracting orange colour using HSV Image.
ThreshImage = cv2.inRange(HSV_Image, np.array([0, 81, 0]), np.array([41, 255, 255]))

# Finding Contours
Contours, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(ThreshImage, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Taking only those contours which have no child contour.
FinalContours = [Contours[i] for i in range(len(Contours)) if Hierarchy[0][i][2] == -1]

# Drawing Contours
Image = cv2.drawContours(Image, FinalContours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("Contours", Image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Resultant Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13KezdGP3W_BcXxTAIWGSx00G-S_odxVO/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that detet small circles by sliding window. when the small cicle area occupied the sliding window area large than 90%(Inscribed circle and square), and less than 100%(avoiding sliding window move in the bigger cicle). this position is a small circle. the largest sliding windows size is the largest small cicle size. Hope some help.

in addtion, on the result of Piglet, apply k-means, which k = 2, you can get a binary image, and then use findcontours to count the small circles.